# Problemas con update android studio 2.1.3

Tags: android

Obtengo el mensaje de error al sincronizar con gradle 2.14 y jdk 1.8:

> Gradle sync failed: Could not initialize class
>   com.google.common.reflect.Types$NativeTypeVariableEquals

Cuando doy clean al project me da este otro error al sincronizar

> Error:Could not create an instance of type    org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated.
>   Could not initialize class     com.google.common.reflect.Types$NativeTypeVariableEquals

o en ocaciones este

> Error:(class: com/google/common/reflect/Types$TypeVariableImpl, method: isAnnotationPresent signature: (Ljava/lang/Class;)Z) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.yas.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.1.1'
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}*
```

Comment: Agrega más información de tu error. Tu build.gradle. Codigo.

Comment: buil gradle 2.14.1

Comment: yo estaba trabajando con la 1.2 y todo bien cuando actulize me sale el error  tengo jdk 1.8

Comment: y no puedo conectarme ainterne a traves del android studio porque me conecto con proxy en Cuba

Comment: agrega tu build.gradle por favor Yasel!

Comment: pero agregalos en tu pregunta.

Comment: ya organize mejor la pregunta espero que puedan ayudarme saludos

Answer (score 1):

Revisando tu problema, al final de este [Thread](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Unusual-exception-when-importing-Gradle-%20project-into-Android-Studio-td5712514.html) comenta un ingeniero de Gradle la configuración que requieres cuando son definidos directorios dentro del `build.gradle`, en tu caso:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Ya que tu problema es similar al thread.

Sin embargo me parece que lo que provoca el problema es que no tienes definido el .jar que contiene la clase dentro de tu folder `/libs` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esa librería la tengo dentro de external Libraries muchas gracias de todas formas

Comment: me sigue dando el error espero ayuda